# Can I receive bitcoins to a address which was used 2017

Tags: address

I have a receiving address which was used in 2017,someone said they sent me coins to that address 5 years later (today) is that address still mine,its showing nothing since last time i used in 2017?

Answer (score 1):

Addresses are forever. If someone sends sats there, then anyone with access to an up-to-date blockchain explorer can verify if the transaction successfully completed.

Owning . It's difficult to know if you're the only owner, but verifying you have a key is easy

"Ownership" of an address really just means control, "being in unique possession of a corresponding private key". In other words, whoever knows the private key for an address can spend any coins there.